# Generate 64 Character Hex String Respectively

Tags: php, string, algorithm, lua, hex

I need an algorithm/code/example in PHP or Lua to generate a series of 64 Character Hex String Respectively.

Like this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000D 
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018
.
.
.
```

Comment: `I wrote this code in …` *What* `this code`? Include it in your question. (Use a code block for blocks of code. For input/output, I recommend *block quotes*.)

Comment: @greybeard I removed them. It's not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `printf` hex formatting code.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    printf("%064X\n", $i);
}
```

`X` format means to print hex with uppercase letters. `064` means to print it in a 64 character field with leading zeros.

---

Similarly in lua:

```
for i=1,1000 do
    print (string.format("%064X", i))
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Barmar. I was forgot everything about `printf `. is this function fast? Because I must generate alots of this type of string I need a faster and faster way. I converted `for` to `while (true)` in order to generate all strings. What is the end number of this loop?

Comment: It's not possible to generate *all* 64-digit strings. There are over 10^77 of them. If you generated a billion of them every second it would take 3x10^30 years.

Comment: Is there a fastest way? After I generated each of this strings I do a few computes then compare it with my string. If final string equals to my string, script will print it's HEX code. Are you have any idea to speed up this process?

Comment: You could use an odometer algorithm to increment the last digit, then when it wraps around you recurse on the next digit, and so on.

Comment: Can you provide an algorithm/code/example about odometer algorithm?

Comment: I probably could, but I won't. You're a programmer, start programming. If you can't get it to work, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.